# parameters/ methods in Java

Tags: java, methods, parameters

the code is meant to show the area of the rectangle and then the perimeter. As you can see in the code below the length is 10 and the width is 15. We have to use parameters and methods to get the answer. However, the output is only the area and I can't get the perimeter to also appear when the code is run. If anyone could please help fix just the mistakes now that would be amazing. Thank you.

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println (area(10,15));
    }
/**
* Returns the area of a rectangle
*/
    public static int area (int length, int width)
    {
        return length * width;
    }
/**
* Returns the perimeter of the rectangle
*/
    public static int perimeter (int length, int width)
    {
        return 2 * (length + width);
    }
}
```

p.s I understand the method for the perimeter section is totally wrong, I am new so I was using the area one to try get the perimeter but this was the best I could do.
Edit: very sorry for the earlier mistake, I have updated my question now, it is very late where I live right now lol

Comment: You don't believe that a 10*15 area is 150? It is.

Comment: I have now just realised that lol, sorry just got told to change the length and width so it completely threw me off. I'll update the question :)

Comment: @QBrute oh yea, sorry I take it back then, I'm brainded atm

Comment: @emily You're only printing the result of `area`. Just add another line where you print with a call to `perimeter`

Comment: Your perimeter calculation is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To also print out the perimeter, call the `perimeter` method with the same values as you did for the `area` method in the main method like so:

```
System.out.println(perimeter(10, 15));
```